# Windows WorkFlow 3.5 to 4.0 Migration Issue

Tags: workflow-foundation

I have migrated my sample WF 3.5 project to 4.0. I am having lot of issues related to migration.

Is there any article/link which will help in solving these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a migration guidance on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee264175.aspx) and a WF Migration Kit [here](http://wf.codeplex.com/).

That said, Wf4 is a completely new product and not backward compatible with WF3. There is an interop activity that works in a limited number of scenarios but basically the best approach is to rewrite the workflow part of your application. If you did the smart thing, and separated the how things work from the when they are executed, you should be able to reuse most of your code because it is in regular classes and the workflow are only about when a piece is executed.

And of course there is always the option of just continuing with WF3 for the time being. The complete WF3 stack is still there in .NET 4 and everything will just work if you recompile in .NET 4.